# AR Image recognition from native development to Cross-Platform

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, augmented-reality, image-recognition

I have developed an AR image recognition app natively using iOS development.

However, my company requirements have changed and they want the app to be available on multiple platforms (iOS and Andriod).

- I'm looking for a solution to how this will be done?
- What is the best software/platform to develop it?

The functionality of the App:

The app identifies objects and tells you a related article/video/animation/website.

I'm open to any suggestions/ideas.

Thank you

Comment: You may want to provide more details as AR is a category of features and image recognition is another set of features.

Comment: Basically, its Image Recognition app using ARKit ios framework

Comment: What does the user do and what does the user see. Face mask app? Identify 3-D item like chair or apple, some sort of AR 3D game?

Comment: Please check the update on the request

Comment: So using this feature of ARKit? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/scanning_and_detecting_3d_objects

Comment: yes, that's right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204505/discussion-between-morrison-chang-and-mr-kld).